# Python thinks code the is wrong

Tags: python, syntax-error

Hi in my python script i keeps saying this code is wrong,

```
print "mix up script (c) Ioan Loosley"
```

After it runs python ide highlights the " at the end does any one know why is doing that.

The only line above this code says, `import random`

sorry just noticed thanks to one of the comments that i wasn't using python 2.7

Comment: Please show is *all* your code *and* the exception.

Comment: Which version of Python are you using?

Comment: Also, an IDE is not Python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am going to assume you are using python 3.0?

You need to include parenthesis like so:

```
 print("mix up script (c) Ioan Loosley")
```

http://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html#print-is-a-function